# Understanding Linux printing systems

Tags: printing

I have a HP Laser Jet 1020 connected by USB to my Laptop running Linux.

How does printing work on Linux?

More specifically what are HPLIP, CUPS and Foomatics; their differences, the inter-relationship between them and which should I use to print?

Answer (score 3):

- CUPS is the main printing system
- HPLIP and Foomatic are two batches of drivers that CUPS uses.
- HPLIP comes with a fancy set of frontend tools to interface and configure the printer. In the backend they're just setting CUPS settings but they can be useful.

If more than one is available for your printer, I'd start with the HPLIP. It's [well supported for your printer](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_1020.html). The Foomatic driver probably works well too.

Comment: I've never had any problem with the Foomatic driver for my HP 1020. However, I believe with HPLIP you can do stuff like double sided printing. I.E. HPLIP prints out odd-numbered pages first, then warns you to turn the stack of paper over before printing out the even-numbered pages in reverse order.